# Pandas - Calculate the mean of Timestamps

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm having trouble with calculating the mean of Timestamps.

I have a few values with Timestamps in my Data Frame, and I want to aggregate the values into a single value with the sum of all values and the weighted mean of the appropriate Timestamps

My input is:

```
         Timestamp        Value
ID      
0   2013-02-03 13:39:00     79
0   2013-02-03 14:03:00     19
1   2013-02-04 11:36:00     2
2   2013-02-04 12:07:00     2
3   2013-02-04 14:04:00     1
```

And I want to aggregate the data using the ID index.

I was able to sum the Values using

```
manp_func = {'Value':['sum'] }

new_table =table.groupby(level='ID).agg(manp_func)
```

but, how can I find the weighted mean of the Timestamps related to the values?

Thanks

S.A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
agg = lambda x: (x['Timestamp'].astype('i8') * (x['Value'].astype('f8') / x['Value'].sum())).sum()

new_table = table.groupby(level='ID').apply(agg).astype('i8').astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Output of `new_table`

```
ID
0   2013-02-03 13:43:39.183673344
2   2013-02-04 11:51:30.000000000
3   2013-02-04 14:04:00.000000000
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The main idea is to compute the weighted average as normal, but there are a couple of subtleties:

- You have to convert the datetime64[ns] to an integer offset first because multiplication is not defined between those two types. Then you have to convert it back.
- Calculating the weighted sum as `sum(a*w)/sum(w)` will result in overflow (`a*w` is too large to be represented as an 8-byte integer), so it has to be calculated as `sum(a*(w/sum(w))`.

Comment: The last casting doesn't work for me. when I omit the astype('i8').astype('datetime64[ns]') in the end - everything works (but of ourse I get huge numbers). if I leave it on I get this error - "'float' object has no attribute 'astype'". Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Give it a go now, I had butchered the sample when pasting it

Answer (score 0):

**Preparing a sample dataframe:**

```
# Initiate dataframe
date_var = "date"
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', '2018-08-05 17:06:01'],
                        ['A', '2018-08-05 17:06:02'],
                        ['A', '2018-08-05 17:06:03'],
                        ['B', '2018-08-05 17:06:07'],
                        ['B', '2018-08-05 17:06:09'],
                        ['B', '2018-08-05 17:06:11']],
                  columns=['column', date_var])

# Convert date-column to proper pandas Datetime-values/pd.Timestamps
df[date_var] = pd.to_datetime(df[date_var])
```

**Extraction of the desired average Timestamp-value:**

```
# Extract the numeric value associated to each timestamp (epoch time)
# NOTE: this is being accomplished via accessing the .value - attribute of each Timestamp in the column
In:
[tsp.value for tsp in df[date_var]]
Out:
[
    1533488761000000000, 1533488762000000000, 1533488763000000000,
    1533488767000000000, 1533488769000000000, 1533488771000000000
]

# Use this to calculate the mean, then convert the result back to a timestamp
In:
pd.Timestamp(np.nanmean([tsp.value for tsp in df[date_var]]))
Out:
Timestamp('2018-08-05 17:06:05.500000')
```